# Javascript Odd or even Algorithm question?

Tags: javascript

I already know this wouldn't work If I passed something like 0 or 1, but why wouldn't it work If it managed to work with 2 and 7.
I'm still new to Javascript programming so I'm just trying to figure out why adding 
if(number = number % 2 == 0) or the other wouldn't work.
Here's the code:

```js
function even_or_odd(number) {
  if(number = number % 2 == 0) {
  return "Even"
  }else if(number = number % 2 !== 0) {
  return "Odd"
  }
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `number = number % 2 == 0`? Wouldn't you just want `number % 2 == 0`? And why even bother with a condition in your else? If something's not even, it has to be odd

Comment: Yes I am, I'm just trying to have a more in depth look as to why adding "number =" , wouldn't work as far as I can tell if I called the function with 0 its basically stating " 0 = 0==0) , but I am not sure, so I'm just trying to break down what is going down in that if statement and why it would be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=` is an [*assignment operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators). It assigns the value of the expression on the right-hand side to a variable on the left-hand side.

`==` is an [*equality operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_operators). It tests the equality of the result of both the left and right-hand-side expression.

Since you're using `=` and inadvertently assigning `number` to the value of your expression on the right, it will always evaluate to a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value and return `"Even"`. To fix, remove the `number =` from each of the expressions:

```js
function even_or_odd(number) {
  if(number % 2 == 0) {
  return "Even"
  }else if(number % 2 !== 0) {
  return "Odd"
  }
};

console.log(even_or_odd(0));
console.log(even_or_odd(1));
```

MDN has [a great section on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#Assignment_within_the_conditional_expression) in their `if...else` page:

> It is advisable to not use simple assignments in a conditional expression, because the assignment can be confused with equality when glancing over the code. For example, do not use the following code:
>
> ```
> if (x = y) {
>    /* do something */
> }
> ```
>
> If you need to use an assignment in a conditional expression, a common practice is to put additional parentheses around the assignment. For example:
>
> ```
> if ((x = y)) {
>    /* do something */
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks , I do know how to fix the problem I just wanted to know more in depth of how its working because i changed it to if(number == number % 2 == 0) { return "even"}, I know this doesn't fix the problem but I was just trying to break down why It wouldn't work when I pass a value of 0, but it does work when I am passing a value of 2 so I can have a better grasp of how its all working

Comment: so far from what I can tell if I pass a value of 0 the if statement is turning into if(0 == true) {return "even"} , which 0 doesn't equal the value of true it is equal to 0 so it returns an error.  I'm sorry If i'm not making any sense here I'm still new to programming.

Comment: The expression in that case would be evaluated left-to-right: `number == number % 2` would evaluate to `TRUE` (`0 == 0`). Then, the interpreter would attempt to compare the resulting `TRUE` value to `0` (which is a [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)), (`TRUE == FALSE`), which would always evaluate to `FALSE`.

Comment: Thank you! sorry about the long question. My head gets very stuck on details about why does this do this, so I end up having to break everything down into steps to understand it better.

Comment: You'll notice every programmer goes through the same steps all the time; it's a foundational skill that you'll gain as you get more experience. Even the best programmers sometimes use the [Rubber duck method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) to talk themselves through an issue.